# detecting hyperbolic regions in an image matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I have grey scale images as shown (it is scanned profile of an actual construction bridge). I would like to identify or detect hyperbolic variations or regions in it (and preferably separate them in the form of boxes as shown in another image). I have tried canny edge detector, texture segmentation and other methods, but they are not as reliable ..i.e., they don't have high degree of accuracy. The problems associated with this are:
a) Sometimes the hyperbolic variations are too close..so I have to stretch the image and adjust contrast.
b) Sometimes the region contrast is too light or heavily distorted.. but I still wanna detect them.. Please suggest a suitable method or code to identify it.. I have attached some sample images. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

sample image:

[image: sample image]

result needed - sample:

[image: result needed - sample]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mgskgb62cz5mrhv/FILE____022%20P_1.png?dl=0 another sample image

Comment: Hi Kashif, did you try Hough transform to detect circular part. Then you can take the loose end of circular part to find extending edge using straight edge detection.

Comment: well its not circular but hyperbolic but I'll see if it works for me. Thanks for the suggestion..any other, please share! @PervezAlam

Comment: Hi @Kashif, I am talking about circular part of hyperbola.. The bending part.. where asymptotes bend to meet..

Comment: If this is a breathing pattern, you shoudl try to fit some sort of Sin^4 wave to it, then each phase would be one of the boxes